# Load images for CSS injected through CssResource

Tags: java, gwt

One way to inject CSS in a GWT app is through CssResource, however if the CSS loads images, what would be the approach so that the images could still be loaded (in a efficient manner) despite the CSS path now is relative the the module name of the GWT project.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use image sprites in your CSS, in other words you can reference the image resources in your client bundle.

http://www.gwtproject.org/doc/latest/DevGuideClientBundle.html#Image_Sprites